# Django settings.py file load twice and second time unable to get environment variable

Tags: django, django-settings

My settings.py is loaded twice each time web server start.

Strangely the first time it load, the file can get value from environment variable `os.getenv("django_environment")` but when it reload second time it just failed to get any value for the same statement.

Any idea why? I'm using Gunicorn, Nginx, Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

**--noreload
Disables the auto-reloader. This means any Python code changes you make while the server is running will not take effect if the particular Python modules have already been loaded into memory.
**

Because django want make your modify effect, and you needn't restart.